# Breaking out of IF Statement - EXIT;

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I've got a statement like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    if (!confirm('Continue ?')) { return false; }

    if (!$("#all").is(':checked')) {
        $(".A").each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == '0') { alert ('A - This Value Must Be Set'); return false; }
        });

        $(".B").each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == '0') { alert ('B - This Value Must Also Be Set'); return false; }
        });

        $(".C").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length < 1) { alert ('C - This Must Be Set'); return false; } 
            if (!$.isNumeric(this.value)) { alert ('C - Only Numeric Values'); return false; }
        });
    }
});
```

If any class 'A' has the value of 0 then I get an alert:

> A - This Value Must Be Set

This is fine but then I get checked by the class 'B' & class 'C' check.
What I want is to stop all extra from checking that either an A, B & C alerts are sent.

How can I do this?

Comment: Oddly, `return true` should do the trick.

Comment: I believe `return false` inside an `each` loop will simply skip the iteration it's on and head to the next, similar to `continue` in a `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to use if condition else to do that. Try something like this,

```
if (!$("#all").is(':checked')) {
    var foundA = false;
    var foundB = false;
    var foundC = false;
    $(".A, .B, .C").each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        if($(this).val() == '0') {
          if (self.prop('class') === 'A' && foundA === false){
            foundA = true;
            alert ('A - This Value Must Be Set');                
          } else if (self.prop('class') === 'B' && foundB === false){
            foundB = true;
            alert ('B - This Value Must Be Set');
          } else if (self.prop('class') === 'c' && foundC === false){
            foundC = true;
            alert ('C - This Value Must Be Set');
          }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but if the user has duplicated the row multiple times and they haven't configured all the values, you end up with multiple alerts are each field is checked. Hence why I want to stop on the first alert received.

Comment: Updated by adding 3 flags. Give a try. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare a variable outside the scope of the each, and exit the function if is setted:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    if (!confirm('Continue ?')) { return false; }

        var stopFunction = false;
        if (!$("#all").is(':checked')) {
            $(".A").each(function() {
                if($(this).val() == '0') { alert ('A - This Value Must Be Set'); stopFunction = true; return false; }
            });

            if(stopFunction)
                return false;

            $(".B").each(function() {
                if($(this).val() == '0') { alert ('B - This Value Must Also Be Set'); stopFunction = true; return false; }
            });

            if(stopFunction)
                return false;

            $(".C").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val().length < 1) { alert ('C - This Must Be Set'); return false; } 
                if (!$.isNumeric(this.value)) { alert ('C - Only Numeric Values'); stopFunction = true; return false; }
            });

            if(stopFunction)
                return false;
        }
});
```